# Realm Swift - Convert an array of results into an array of Ints

Tags: swift, realm

I want to convert the results from my Realm data into Int.

Here is an example of how I want to use this.

```
let results = realm.objects(Data.self)

print(results)
```

However the result is type `Results<Data>` and cannot be converted into a Int but the results is an Int.

Just to be clear I want an array of Int from my results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `Array(realm.objects(RealmType.self))`, which will convert the `Results<RealmType>` instance into an `Array<RealmType>`.

However, there are other serious flaws with your code. First of all, neither of the last two lines will compile, since firstly `realm.objects()` accepts a generic input argument of type `Object.Type` and `Data` doesn't inherit from `Object`. You can't directly store `Data` objects in `Realm`, you can only store `Data` as a property of a Realm `Object` subclass.

Secondly, `myArray[results]` is simply wrong, since `results` is supposed to be of type `Results<RealmType>`, which is a collection, so using it to index an `Array`  cannot work (especially whose `Element` type is different).

Comment: I have rephrased my post please check it again just realised it was very confusing, also to be clear data is my class with the subclass object.

Comment: @Callum9966 you shouldn't create types that have the same name as existing types since it can lead to confusion both for you and other people working with your code and for the compiler when using type inference. Moreover, your question became even less clear. There's no relation between `Results<Data>` and `Int`, so it's really unclear how and why do you want an `Int` from the `Results` instance. Including the definition of your `Data` class and explaining clearly what is of type `Int` and what do you want to do with it would help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that based on the number of results from the database, you want to select an object from the array.

You can get the number of items in an array with `.count`. Be certain that an object exists at the specified index in the array, or your application will crash!

```swift
let numberOfResults = results.count
if myArray.count > numberOfResults {
    let object = myArray[numberOfResults]
    print(object)
}
```

Comment: I have rephrased my question which is a lot more clear please check again